# Vba code to set the margin of selected text in indent level 2

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

Hi I have the following mention code which sets the indent level for second paragraph . I have two issues with this code.

1. On selecting more than one paragraphs the indentation will work only on Last paragraph Selected.
2. **The margin could not be set with this code . As I want "before text 1.2" and "Special Hanging by 0.46 cm" to be incorporated**

   Sub selectedLevel()
   Dim otr2 As TextRange2
    ' assumes the placeholder is selected
   Set otr2 = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(GetPara)
   With otr2.ParagraphFormat
       .IndentLevel = 2
   End With
   End Sub

Function GetPara() As Long
   Dim lngStart As Long
   Dim oshp As Shape
   Dim L As Long
   On Error Resume Next
   lngStart = ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Start
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Exit Function
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
   Set oshp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
   If (oshp.HasTextFrame) Then
      For L = 1 To oshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count
         If (oshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(L).Start <= lngStart) And ((oshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(L).Start + oshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(L).Length - 1) >= lngStart) Then
            GetPara = L
            Exit Function
         End If
      Next L
   End If
End Function

Please help me in customizing this code and run the subroutine .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have worked out with my first question pertaining to Margin .

However when I select the multiple paragraphs. All the parapraphs doesn't get indented

The code below is for having the Predefined MARGIN

```
    Sub selectedLevel()
    Dim otr2 As TextRange2
Set otr2 = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(GetPara)
With otr2.ParagraphFormat
.LeftIndent = 0.9 * 39
.FirstLineIndent = -(0.5 * 29)
  End With
  End Sub




 Function GetPara() As Long
  Dim lngStart As Long
 Dim oshp As Shape
 Dim L As Long
 On Error Resume Next
  lngStart = ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Start
  If err.Number <> 0 Then
   Exit Function
  End If
   On Error GoTo 0
    Set oshp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
   If (oshp.HasTextFrame) Then
     For L = 1 To oshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count
       If (oshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(L).Start <= lngStart) And 
   ((oshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(L).Start + 
        oshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(L).Length - 1) >= lngStart) Then
          GetPara = L
          Exit Function
        End If
       Next L
     End If
     End Function
```

Please help me with applying this subroutine in all paragraphs.